# Finding the pattern in a sequence of polynomials

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a series that has a weird behavior, as follows

$A(1)=x_1$

$A(2)={3\over4}x_1+{1\over4}x_2$

$A(3)={2\over3}x_1+{1\over4}x_2+{1\over12}x_3$

$A(4)={5\over8}x_1+{1\over4}x_2+{3\over32}x_3+{1\over32}x_4$

$A(5)={3\over5}x_1+{1\over4}x_2+{1\over10}x_3+{3\over80}x_4+{1\over80}x_5$

I want to have a general formula for $A(n)$, which I know looks like

$A(n)={n+1\over2n}x_1+{1\over4}x_2 + \sum_{i=3}^n \alpha_i x_i$

but I just don't know what is $\alpha_i$. Any ideas?

EDIT. Second part of the question here [Finding expected distances and sequences](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2363295/finding-expected-distances-and-sequences)

Comment: Could you give some context of where you found this or how the pattern is meant to continue? I can't see any obvious pattern myself, especially since we only have a few terms of $x_3, x_4, x_5$. Edit: I see the last term is $\frac{1}{n(2^{n-1})}x_n$... but the rest?

Comment: I can see a slight pattern with the terms given  $${1\over 3}\alpha_{n-1}=\alpha_n$$  not sure how the coefficients are changing as n is though. at A(n) for clarification.

Comment: All coefficients add to one, just a note.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the "common denominator" in $n^{th}$ row is $n 2^{n-1}$ & the numerators then generate the sequence $1,3,8,20,48,\cdots$ which have the formula $(n+2)2^{n-1}$ https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C3%2C8%2C20%2C48&language=english&go=Search

So the formula is
\begin{eqnarray*}
A(n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{(n+2-i)2^{n-i-1}}{n 2^{n-1}} x_i=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{(n+2-i)}{n 2^{i}} x_i.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: You could simplify the factor of xi in the sum to (n+2-i)/(n*2^i)

Comment: Good thinking @Penguino ... I will edit.

Comment: Thank you all. Here is the reasoning behind this question - which possess an even harder problem https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2363295/finding-expected-distances-and-sequences